# Send an email with a blank subject

Tags: vba, outlook

I am a professor interacting with students who do not respond to emails, but who do respond to text messages.  So, I am writing an Outlook userform to generate text messages that are sent by Outlook to students' cell phones, e.g., by using email addresses that target the student's cell phone text message service like this:  5405551212@mms.att.net

The problem I am running into is that I don't want to have a Subject for these text messages because that Subject is added as the first line of each text sent to the student and is confusing and looks weird, but, the VBA code olMail.Send will throw this error when the Subject is blank:  "Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Outlook does not recognize one or more names."  The names for olMail.To and olMail.CC are fine and the error goes away when I add a non-blank Subject.

Is there a way to programmatically force Outlook to send the email with a blank subject?  I have not been able to find a solution searching online other than to make the subject " " (a space)--but that is not an ideal solution because it still adds a "blank" line at the top of each text message because of the space.

I could probably use olMail.Display and then use SendKeys to send the email and answer "Yes" when I am asked if I want to send the email without a subject, but that is clunky.

How can I skip the error and send the email without a subject using VBA?

EDIT:
Here's the code that I was using to add recipients to the mailitem:

```
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olMail As MailItem
    olMail.To = Me.tbxEmailAddress  'this would be something like 5405551212@mms.att.net
    olMail.CC = "someemail@notmail.com"  'this would be my own email address
    olMail.Subject = ""   'blank subject
    olMail.Body = Replace(Me.tbxTexts, vbCrLf, "")  'remove extra hard returns
    olMail.Send   'this would throw the error mentioned above,
                  'but if I changed olMail.Subject = "" to
                  'olMail.Subject = "This is the subject" then no error would occur
```

Using @Eugene Astafiev's information below, I cobbled together a working solution like this:

```
    Dim myRecipients As Outlook.Recipients
    Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olMail As MailItem

    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    olMail.Subject = ""   'blank subject
    olMail.Body = Replace(Me.tbxTexts, vbCrLf, "")  'remove extra hard returns
    Set myRecipient = olMail.Recipients.Add(tbxEmailAddress)
    myRecipient.Type = olTo  'Type is:  olBCC, olCC, olOriginator, or olTo
    Set myRecipient = olMail.Recipients.Add("someemail@notmail.com")
    myRecipient.Type = olBCC

    Set myRecipients = olMail.Recipients
    If Not myRecipients.ResolveAll Then
     For Each myRecipient In myRecipients
       If Not myRecipient.Resolved Then
         MsgBox "Could not resolve: " & myRecipient.Name
       End If
     Next
    End If
    olMail.Send   'no error now!
```

Interestingly, no email address using the myRecipients collection ever reported being unable to be resolved.  However, when I tried to resolve the individual myRecipient object/item using myRecipient.Resolve then the text message email address (e.g., 5405551212@mms.att.net) would fail to resolve but my own email address would resolve fine.

Maybe this has something to do with 5405551212@mms.att.net not being an address in my Address Book or Contacts?

At any rate, it does send now.  (Note:  prior to using the myRecipients.ResolveAll, I did succeed in getting the code I originally had to work by using olMail.Display and then olMail.Send and then using SendKeys "%s" twice--the first time to "click" the Send button and the second time to "click" the "Send Anyway" button when Outlook complained there was no subject.  But, clearly the VBA code approach is far superior.)

Thanks to everyone for you help!

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` ? make sure you understand that line of code, may be there better solution -can we look at your code?

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the subject - it means one or more recipients are not valid.What is your code that adds the recipients and sends the message?

Comment: @0m3r I tried Resume Next and ignoring the error, but then the message fails to send.

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko as noted, the recipients *are* valid because when I use the same recipients and add a subject, the email sends fine without the error.

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko I am using Outlook 2016.  I agree that the error is referencing the recipients, it just doesn't make sense that the recipients are the problem when using the same code and recipients but adding a Subject the code sends the email fine.  I did manage to get it working with the ResolveAll for recipients, but I still don't understand why I did not have to ResolveAll when the Subject was not blank.

Comment: @DRC - that is why I asked you about your code: you need to show *how* you add the recipients.

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko, I added code above as requested--I never resisted adding code.  I disagree with the statement "The error has nothing to do with the subject" since when the subject was not blank, the code for recipients worked.  While the error may refer to recipients, the error goes away when I changed the subject even when the recipients were the same, so the error oddly seems to have *something* to do with the subject.  I also disagree with the statement "one or more recipients are not valid."  Throughout the whole process I've used exactly the same recipients but now the code works.

Comment: @DRC - Nope, the value of the subject makes no difference at all. It is a red herring. And you can use Recipients.Add or your can set To/CC/BCC properties. The only problem you can potentially run into is if you include carriage returns or attempt to separate the recipients with anything but ";". You can also run into a problem if the recipient name includes ";" or (if that's your locale's list separator) ",". In that case Recipients.Add might behave differently since it assumes a single name is being added and never parses the provided value (unlike To/Cc/BCC property setters).

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko, oh!  So you wrote, "Recipients.Add...never parses the provided value (unlike To/Cc/BCC property setters)."  Is *that* why I can successfully send emails with Recipients.Add without an error but .To and .CC properties do cause errors?  Because Recipients.Add does not parse the value?  I really want to understand why my original code did not work, and this seems to be the first information that would explain that.  It does seem to be related to the email address I am trying to send To is not an Email1entry in my address book (although it *is* an Email2entry).  Thank you!

Comment: What is the exact string value that you were setting to the To property?

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko, I cannot post the exact string value because it is a private mobile phone number converted to an email address in order to send text messages via email. But, it would be something like:   olMail.To = "5405551212@mms.att.net"   That value would be the Email2address value in my Outlook contacts for the contact for whom that is the cell phone number converted to an email address in order to send a text message from Outlook's email interface. The only difference between the actual value and the one shown here is the phone number I was using was a valid cell phone number. Thx

Comment: No ";" or ","? And it is always a single email address, not multiple, right?

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko, correct:  No semicolons nor any other punctuation.  Just the @ between the cell phone number and domain address and the periods in the domain address itself.  Yes, it is always a single email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook doesn't require setting up the Subject line before submitting items. Use the [Recipients.ResolveAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients.resolveall) method which attempts to resolve all the Recipient objects in the Recipients collection against the Address Book.

```
Sub CheckRecipients() 
 Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim myRecipients As Outlook.Recipients
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 

 Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
 Set myRecipients = myItem.Recipients 
 myRecipients.Add("Eugene Astafiev") 
 myRecipients.Add("Nate Sun") 
 myRecipients.Add("Dan Wilson") 
 
 If Not myRecipients.ResolveAll Then
  For Each myRecipient In myRecipients
    If Not myRecipient.Resolved Then 
      MsgBox myRecipient.Name 
    End If
  Next
 End If 
 
End Sub
```

You may find the following articles helpful:

- [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/)
- [How To: Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/)

Comment: Thank you, @Eugene Astafiev.  Using the Recipients collection was necessary.  See my code above in the edited post that used your approach to solve the problem.